# Convert to DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a question, someone could help transform this code (used in codebehind ) for use by dependyProperty ?

This code gives the focus to the first item of listview . THX!!!!!!

```
    private void ItemContainerGeneratorOnStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (lvResultado.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            var index = lvResultado.SelectedIndex;
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                var item = lvResultado.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListViewItem;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically, I want to write something like: `local:FocusFirstElement.Focus="True"` in my XAML instead of writing this code for every list view.

Comment: Thats an event, which isn't really what you use DPs for. Could you be more clear about why you feel a DP should be used there, and how it would work?

Comment: That still doesn't really sound like a use case for a DP. You use those when you need to allow the UI to bind to a property of a user control/dependency object. What about your existing approach isn't working?

Comment: I thought it was the fastest and with less code option .

xmlns: FocusFirstElement.Focus = "true "

something like that.

Comment: I edited your post to include your last comment (which was the key!) and remove the solution as I describe in the comment on my answer. Please feel free to revert any changes if you feel I changed your intent.

Answer (score 1):

What you are is really an **attached behavior**, which is implemented via an **attached property** which is really a special **dependency property** (which you seem to have hit upon already).

First, create an attached property. This is most easliy accomplished using the `propa` snippet:

```
    public static bool GetFocusFirst(ListView obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(FocusFirstProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFocusFirst(ListView obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FocusFirstProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusFirstProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FocusFirst", typeof(bool), 
           typeof(ListViewExtension), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

I'm assuming this is in a static class called `ListViewExtenstion`. Then, handle the property changed event:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusFirstProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FocusFirst", typeof(bool), 
           typeof(ListViewExtension), new PropertyMetadata(false, HandleFocusFirstChanged));

 static void HandleFocusFirstChanged(
  DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

In that handler you would check the current value (in `e`) and register or deregister for the appropriate event on the `ListView` contained in `depObj`. Then you would use your existing code to set the focus. Something like:

```
 static void HandleFocusFirstChanged(
  DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     ListView lv = (ListView)debObj;

     if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        lv.StatusChanged += MyLogicMethod;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help, I have a similar code , but not working . The property is called when the ListView is created, but when I do a search and you have to show the listview not working.

Comment: Sorry! Go to EDIT in original post.

Comment: After sweating blood to achieve it work. You can reduce the code or add something? Go to edit :) and thx for all!!!

Comment: @avechuche That's basically my code, so if you feel I *missed* something, then feel free to suggest an edit to my post. On Stack Overflow, posting the "solution" code in the question is not necessary and is just noise. If my answer solved your problem, do consider clicking the check mark next to it to mark it as "the" answer. Doing is so is optional, and provides you and me with some reputation. Glad I was able to help solve your problem!